# What are the different directories of an Homebrew installation (/usr/local/...) for

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to get a hold of the structure of my Homebrew setup and would like to know what these different directories in /usr/local are for:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/Caskroom
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/etc
/usr/local/Frameworks
/usr/local/Homebrew
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/opt
/usr/local/remotedesktop
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/var
```

**Homebrew**

contains the Homebrew app

**Cellar**

contains all the racks someone installs through Homebrew. A rack contains the different versions of an application

But the rest: bin, etc, Framworks, include, lib, ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of these directories are part of the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard), and so have a standardised purpose regardless of the fact that you're using Homebrew.

My answer is based mainly from [hier(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) for directories that both macOS and Linux share, and the [MacPorts wiki](https://guide.macports.org/#internals.hierarchy) for more macOS specific answers.

#### Non-Homebrew Specific

> /usr/local/bin

This is where your standard **executable files** are stored. e.g. When you type `vim` into the terminal, the file that's run is stored here.

> /usr/local/etc

These are **local configuration files**. Shell completion files are examples of this (when you hit tab to autofill a command's options).

> /usr/local/include

This is where **header files** are stored that are used by C programs. These contain pre-defined functions.

> /usr/local/lib

**Object libraries** are stored here.

> /usr/local/opt

This contains **static files**, including licenses, READMEs, and install receipts.

> /usr/local/sbin

These are **executable files** that which aren't normally run by standard users. e.g. System programs and administration utilities.

> /usr/local/share

This folder contains **architecture-independent files**. Examples might include documentation and man pages.

> /usr/local/var

**Files which may change in size** can be stored here. Log files are a good example.

#### macOS Specific

> /usr/local/Frameworks

This is for **native macOS frameworks**. Python makes use of this for storing the Python app and executable.

> /usr/local/remotedesktop

I'm guessing that this stores files from **[Apple Remote Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Remote_Desktop)**.

#### Homebrew Specific

> /usr/local/Caskroom

This directory contains named casks (i.e. **applications**) e.g. Firefox, Telegram. See the [Homebrew terminology](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#terminology) page for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations and the links you provided. They really help. To my knowledge Caskroom, Cellar and Homebrew are Homebrew specific. In the other directories such as bin there are quite often symlinks. So this means, that Homebrew writes to this directories too? I guess, that when I need to resurrect a deleted Homebrew formula, it would not be enough to only restore the relative Cellar???

Comment: Thanks for marking this as the answer :) On a new mac, `/usr/local` is empty. It's mainly populated by third-party tools. All of the directories mentioned (except remotedesktop) were written to by Homebrew. They even used to go so far as to take ownership of `/usr/local`! So yes I don't think it's enough to restore just the cellar.